# How to stop JTextField being resized because of weightx=1f?

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I had troubles with GridBagLayout when I shrinked the height of JPanel.
As soon as I solved this trouble I got problem when padding width of the same jpanel.

The problem is for now is that all components are resized to as wide as needed to cover width of jpanel. But if I change their weightx or I change fill property then I get new old problem with shrinking height of jpanel.

Please, copy paste this class to see that :

```
public class DateFormatDemo extends JFrame
{
    JLabel eventLabel = new JLabel("Label : ", SwingConstants.LEFT);
    JTextField eventLabelField = new JTextField("myFirstEvent", 30);
    JLabel timestampLabel = new JLabel("Time stamp : ");
    JLabel timestammpToLabel = new JLabel(" to ");
    JTextField timestampStartField = new JTextField("2011-11-30 12:30:45", 15);
    JTextField timestampEndField = new JTextField("2011-10-12 07:22:50", 15);
    JLabel durationMagnitudeLabel = new JLabel("Duration Magnitude : ");
    JTextField durationMagnitudeMinField = new JTextField("2011-10-12 09:12:40", 15);
    JLabel durationMagnitudeToLabel = new JLabel(" to ");
    JTextField durationMagnitudeMaxField = new JTextField("2011-10-12 11:13:34", 15);
    JButton searchButton = new JButton("search");

    public DateFormatDemo() {
        JPanel searchPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()) {
            Dimension minSize = new Dimension(200, 0);
            Border border = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Search query"),
                    BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 5, 10, 5));

            @Override
            public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
                return minSize;
            }

            @Override
            public Border getBorder() {
                return border;
            }
        };

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(5, 2, 5, 3), 0, 0);
        searchPanel.add(eventLabel, updateGridBagConstraints(gbc, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0f, 0f));
        searchPanel.add(eventLabelField, updateGridBagConstraints(gbc, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1f, 0f));
        searchPanel.add(timestampLabel, updateGridBagConstraints(gbc, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0f, 0f));
        searchPanel.add(timestampStartField, updateGridBagConstraints(gbc, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1f, 0f));
        searchPanel.add(timestammpToLabel, updateGridBagConstraints(gbc, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0f, 0f));
        searchPanel.add(timestampEndField, updateGridBagConstraints(gbc, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1f, 0f));
        searchPanel.add(durationMagnitudeLabel, updateGridBagConstraints(gbc, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0f, 0f));
        searchPanel.add(durationMagnitudeMinField, updateGridBagConstraints(gbc, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1f, 0f));
        searchPanel.add(durationMagnitudeToLabel, updateGridBagConstraints(gbc, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0f, 0f));
        searchPanel.add(durationMagnitudeMaxField, updateGridBagConstraints(gbc, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1f, 0f));
        gbc = updateGridBagConstraints(gbc, 0, 4, 3, 1, 0f, 0f);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.ipadx = 5;
        gbc.ipady = 5;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15, 0, 0, 0);
        searchPanel.add(searchButton, gbc);

        super.getContentPane().add(searchPanel);
        super.pack();
        super.setVisible(true);
    }

    private GridBagConstraints updateGridBagConstraints(GridBagConstraints gbc, int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth,
            int gridheight, float weightx, float weighty) {
        gbc.gridx = gridx;
        gbc.gridy = gridy;
        gbc.gridwidth = gridwidth;
        gbc.gridheight = gridheight;
        gbc.weightx = weightx;
        gbc.weighty = weighty;
        return gbc;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        new DateFormatDemo();
    }
}
```

If you resize width of Jpanel you'll see that textfields are resized too.

Also can you advise smth about border of this jpanel. As you see titled border is too close to topmost label eventLabel.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your problem is only with Border and label?

Comment: Start accepting answers from your previous questions, if you want help in the future.

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly you need help with? Except the labeled border, it's unclear what kind of help you need. If you could provide a screenshot of the wanted look and describe what behavior the components should have, that would be great.

Comment: My problem is that I cannot tell my components not to resize when I move divider or when I resize that panel. Plus the problem is there with titled border because it is too narrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you resize width of Jpanel you'll see that textfields are resized
>   too.

The grid bag layout manager calculates the weight of a column to be the maximum `weightx` of all the components in a column. If the resulting layout is smaller horizontally than the area it needs to fill, the extra space is distributed to each column in proportion to its weight. A column that has a weight of `zero` receives no extra space. So set `wieghtx` of text fields to `zero` of which you don't want to be re-sized in width.

**Edit:**
 `GridBagLayout` respects the *minimum and preferred size* of the component laying out by it. Try with setting them, it should work.

Comment: You are right. And here new old problem arises. When I shrink height of that panel my textfields and button become so small that it is impossible to look at.

Comment: Are you trying to shrink the height even beyond the size it was showed up on the screen ?

Comment: Not I am trying to make height smaller and smaller and one moment my textfields become 1px wide. Then I again increase height and my textfileds again automatically become of correct size. To see this just try to set fill property to NONE in GridBagConstraints constructor

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi, Edited the answer. Check it. But it is just a temporary solution

Comment: No it doesn't because I use fill Both for GridBagConstraints.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi, Did you try setting minimum size to all of your your text fields ? I suspect you didn't before commenting. `fill is Used when the component's display area is *larger* than the component's requested size to determine whether and how to resize the component.`

Answer (score 1):

I not recommended you to do like this :

```
JPanel searchPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()) {
        Dimension minSize = new Dimension(200, 0);
        Border border = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Search query"),
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 5, 10, 5));

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
            return minSize;
        }

        @Override
        public Border getBorder() {
            return border;
        }
    };
```

for that purposes do that in next way:

```
JPanel searchPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
Border border = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Search query"),
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 5, 10, 5));
searchPanel.setBorder(border);
```

It soleves problem with border.

setMinimum size to Parent component:

```
DateFormatDemo dateFormatDemo = new DateFormatDemo();
dateFormatDemo.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 0));
```

Comment: Wise people on stackoverflow told me to never use setMinimumSize and setMaximumSize and setPreferredSize and I began to do the same for borders. Thanks mate.